# Installing and start using juju in ubuntu

Tags: juju

I am new ubuntu user .
I am looking forward to install juju core in ubuntu and learn how to use it.
My environment :

Installed a VM using Oracle Virtual box.
Ubuntu 13.10

How do i install and configure juju core in my environment. Also if someone can help me with some links on how can we establish connectivity between juju core and client.

Answer (score 2):

There is a complete guide to installing, configuring and using Juju in the documentation, which you will find at:

- [jujucharms.com/docs](https://jujucharms.com/docs)

Please let us know if it doesn't cover what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to start at [Getting Started](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/getting-started.html) - that should get you up and running, and has links to configuring to use local LXC containers within your VM.

Answer (score 0):

Official Ubuntu **juju documentation** link https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/

1. An SSH key-pair. If you have not already set one up, you need to generate an appropriate keypair. On Linux : **ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048**
2. To install Juju, you simply need to grab the latest juju-core package from the PPA:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install juju-core
   ```
3. Then follow these steps
   Find the section called **config-LXC** in the juju documentation for more details
4. In this official juju documentation
   Only follow section called **Testing your setup**
5. If you want to create a charms in local environment try this juju documentation link

   Find the section called **authors-charm-writing** for more details
6. If you want to install juju charms store

   ```
   juju deploy juju-gui
   juju expose juju-gui
   ```

Find the section called **commands** for more details

```
juju ssh <container-no>   /* login to the linux container */
juju status /* checking the status */
juju destroy-machine  /* destroy the linux container */ 
juju destroy-unit  /* destroy the an unit */ 
juju destroy-service  /* destroy a service */
```